# How to get keytab file (file name:Test.keytab) using spring config server to client?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, cloud-foundry, spring-config

I'm using spring boot application where it has kerberos authentication.

For kerberos authentication, we need keytab file to login krb5LoginModule.

It is not safe to keep keytab file inside the JAR, so we thought to use spring config server to fetch files outside of JAR.

From Spring config server Docs, I understood, We can consume properties, yml files.

is there any possibilities to fetch keytab file?

Do we get any solution using File system Backend (SearchLocation) in spring config server?

Comment: Refer https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-kerberos/docs/1.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/

Comment: Sorry. We are not using spring-security-kerberos in our application. Could you please help on using spring config server on fetching keytab file?

Comment: You can use the file api to get the file, using it is up to you http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Edgware.SR2/single/spring-cloud.html#_serving_plain_text